# I need to Execute a command-line command inside my PowerShell script, but also to use a store variable from Powershell Inside that command

Tags: powershell, variables, cmd, veracrypt

I'm kind of new to Powershell, but now I need to build a script which takes a backup and encrypts it using Veracrypt.
Fortunately there is a command-line syntax to do that, but for my script I'll use the Powershell's shell instead.
I've managed to call CMD from within my Powershell script, but then I need to user a pre-configured variable along with the command-line command, which I previously set in Powershell.
To make a sense for my request, here's how my script goes:

```
$Folder="e:\shares\Test"

$Size=(Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

& 'C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt Format.exe' /create e:\shares\Test\test.hc /password test /hash sha512 /encryption serpent /filesystem NTFS /size $Size
```

As you can see from above example, I need to make the Veracrypt command make use of the `$Size` variable for the `/size` flag.
That's because I assume that my backup size will change due time.

Is therea way to call my **Powershell** variable from **CMD**?

Comment: So what's wrong with your code at the moment?

Comment: The Veracrypt command fails because it can't read the size input for the volume creation. That's where I needed to use my variable to set the size. But seems like cmd doesn't recognize it.

Comment: So if you hard-code a value instead of using your `$Size` variable; what happens?

Comment: Then the command is successful. But that miss the entire purpose of my script. My backup size will differ from one backup process to another...

Comment: just trying to help you debug the solution `;-)`

Does the value of `$Size` match the value you hard-coded?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is that its not recognized as a variable. Thats all my issue is...thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: to be clear: `/size 10240` works, but `$Size=10240 ... /size $Size` does not?!

Comment: Correct! :) As I said the variable is not recognized by the cmd.exe interprator.

Comment: Now that is maddeningly bizarre! Unfortunately that stumps me at the moment and, without an environment in which I can test your scenario, I don't think I can be of any more assistance. Sorry!

Comment: In your code snippet, `cmd.exe` is _not_ involved: you're simply invoking a _console application_ directly from PowerShell, and passing arguments to it. There are many pitfalls associated with passing arguments to console applications, but the code in your question _should_ work, so there must be something you're not mentioning in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was resolved after changing the source folder! sorry for all the bothering!

Comment: @Shachar: Glad to hear it. I encourage you to _delete_ this question, then, given that it's unlikely to benefit future readers.

Comment: Dont know how to delete it :/